# How can I make a 3D plot of a piecewise function of two variables?

Tags: matlab, plot, surface, piecewise

I am trying to plot the following function in MATLAB:

[image: 1]

The goal is to stitch all of the different conditions into one graph to make an overall CDF graph. What I have tried so far is the following:

```
x=linspace(0,1,20);
y=linspace(0,1,20);
Z=x.^y;
plot3(x,y,Z)
hold on
plot3(x,0,0);
plot3(0,y,0);
```

I am unsure of how to graph 1 for `x>1, y>1` and also if there is a way to make the plot a solid surface for this set of conditions. I have tried using the `rand()` generator to produce 20+ numbers between `0` and `1`, which shows the area that the variables could be located. However, it looks messy when it's a scatter of lines in a given area. I would rather it be a solid surface.

Is there a specific command I can use for this? I have seen in some examples using `Mesh()` to make the graph solid but am not sure if this would work for the set of data.

Comment: You appear to be missing 2 conditions: (`x < 0` and `y > 1`) and (`y < 0` and `x > 1`). Perhaps some of those "and"s should be "or"s?

Comment: Judging the function, are you after something like a 2D colour plot, or a `surface()` plot for true 3D?

Answer (score 6):

You can accomplish this by generating a regular grid of `x` and `y` values with [`meshgrid`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), modifying values in `Z` with [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#d120e1410), and displaying the result with [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html):

```
% Grid points spanning from -1 to 2 for x and y:
[x, y] = meshgrid(linspace(-1, 2, 91));

% Fill Z with zeroes to start (satisfies condition 1 by default):
Z = zeros(size(x));

% Condition 2:
index = (x >= 0) & (x <= 1) & (y >= 0) & (y <= 1);
Z(index) = x(index).*y(index);

% Condition 3:
index = (x >= 0) & (x <= 1) & (y > 1);
Z(index) = x(index);

% Condition 4:
index = (y >= 0) & (y <= 1) & (x > 1);
Z(index) = y(index);

% Condition 5:
Z((x > 1) & (y > 1)) = 1;

% Plot surface:
surf(x, y, Z, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
```

[image]

**Note:** This assumes that unspecified conditions, like (`x < 0` and `y > 1`) and (`y < 0` and `x > 1`), should be zero as well.

Comment: Ever play Civilization IV?  I'm totally getting a flashback: https://www.civfanatics.com/images/civ4/pyramids-sm.jpg.